# Convert this Shell command to be able to use on C language

Tags: c, shell, unix, clang, freebsd

I would like to use the following Shell command in a C language.

```
if uname -a | grep '10.0-RELEASE' || '10.3-RELEASE' >> /dev/null; then
```

I need this for my Programm on freebsd. Please help.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My Programm install libs for freebsd but 10.x has other libs

Answer (score 1):

There is a uname(3) function in libc that will return the information that uname reports in the form of a C struct (struct utsname). grep can be replaced with normal C string comparison though note that your `||` syntax is not valid in the shell. I'd guess you're trying to match 10.0 OR 10.3 in which case you can do two string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You may call system() like the following. But make sure your command works first (to me seems it's not correct).

```
if(system("uname -a | grep '10.0-RELEASE' || '10.3-RELEASE' >> /dev/null"))
{
    // no matches
}
else // matches
{
}
```